# Manually trigger facebook like

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a voting thing on my site. I also attach the facebook `like` plugin to the page. For the user to up-vote, they need to be logged in with facebook-connect. So what I want is when the user clicks up-vote, they automatically `like` the page.

Comment: For the sake of security, I hope the Facebook API doesn't allow this.

Comment: I am fairly certain that performing this action, were it to be possible, is against the Facebook Developer EULA/TOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook "Like" buttons are embedded using an iframe from their domain.  For a variety of cross-domain reasons you will not be able to communicate with the iframe in order to send a `click` event to the iframe.

This is intentional, and Facebook would not allow you to do this as it's essentially a spamming technique.

Comment: What about click-jacking? (Just for the sake of argument, not as an endorsement of such questionable techniques).

Comment: There's a few possible solutions I can think of, but don't want to encourage.  And I'm hopeful that Facebook has written their buttons with enough security in mind to prevent any of the ideas I have.